# How do I get into the folder of a Web App in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

Recently I am trying to use:

```
func azure functionapp publish WebAppName --publish-local-settings -i
```

to publish local.settings.json to a web app (actually an Azure function) but I get this error message:

```
Unable to find project root. Expecting to find one of host.json in project root.
```

I have logged in to Azure with az login but it looks like I need to get into the folder where I have deployed the Azure function where all those json files are.

A little background, we are using Octopus Deploy to deploy to an Azure function. After the deployment, we want to add a step so that the local.setting.json will be used to populate app settings.

So how do we change the current folder to be in the Azure function root where all those json files are?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Because we use Teamcity and Octopus Deploy, publishing it from the local project folder is not an option for us. We probably need to write a post deployment script in Octopus to publish it.

Comment: You can also update the application settings in azure portal, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings. `local.settings` is used for local environment. After you deploy your function to azure, it is displayed as application settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to your local function project folder to run the command, for example, my function project is under MyFunctionProj folder.

[image]

Execute the command

```
func azure functionapp publish tonyfunc --publish-local-settings -i --publish-settings-only
```

[image]

By the way, if you just want to update the settings, you need add `--publish-settings-only` parameter.

Reference:

[Core Tools development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#project-file-deployment)

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for your reminder, added the command text.